# Show (0,1) is not compact

Tags: compactness

Let $I_n=\left(\frac{1}{n},1\right)$. Show that $(0,1)$ is not compact: show that any finite collection of $\{I_n\}$ will not cover $(0,1)$.

Give me a hint.

Comment: This is a straightforward proof.  Take any finite subset of $\{I_n\}$ and exhibit an element of $(0,1)$ not contained in any of the selected $I_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any finite collection out of your set will have an element with the greatest $n$

Comment: If some element has the greatest n, then I need to choose the interval (1/(n+1),1) so that it is not contained in any I_n but it is in (0,1)?

Comment: You just have to find one point that is in $(0,1)$ but not contained in one of the intervals in the finite collection. That proves this finite collection is not a cover of $(0,1)$.  Then you argue you can do that no matter what finite collection you are given.

Comment: I can say that 1/(n+1) qualifies as a point in (0,1)? My argument is that no matter what natural number n we have, there will always be a 1/(n+1) outside of the finite collection but still in (0,1). I can even say 1/(n+2) or 1/(n+3) or 1/(n+60000) if I wanted to, right?

Comment: That is correct.  You can use any of those.